# Laravel Dusk reporting production.ERROR: It is unsafe to run Dusk in production, but i am testing on local

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm running laravel dusk on my development machine.

The dusk tests run fine but at points during the process, a production error will be reported as shown below in the .log snippet

This typically causes the browser tests to fall over at the point that the production.error is reported in the log.

I believe everything is set up correctly.
I have created a .env.dusk.local env file.
Dusk tests are persisting to an sql database specifically created for dusk testing .

The env variable in the .env.dusk.local file is set to APP_ENV=testing
The env variable in the .env file is set to APP_ENV=local

Putting

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "laravel/dusk"
        ]
    }
},
```

into composer.json just prevents the dusk tests from running.

I've replicated the problem on two separate Windows 10 dev machines.
I've replicated on laravel 5.8 and 5.7 for the same application i'm building.
Everything else is running fine in the application: unit tests etc.
The dusk tests all run fine apart from this intermittent error.

```
[2019-09-06 11:47:28] testing.DEBUG: >test1: start  

[2019-09-06 11:47:39] testing.DEBUG: messages reporting assert passes etc.  
[2019-09-06 11:47:39] testing.DEBUG: messages reporting assert passes etc.
[2019-09-06 11:47:39] testing.DEBUG: messages reporting assert passes etc. 
[2019-09-06 11:47:39] testing.DEBUG: messages reporting assert passes etc.  
[2019-09-06 11:47:39] testing.DEBUG: messages reporting assert passes etc.
```

...about 12 seconds in to the test each time...

```
[2019-09-06 11:47:39] testing.DEBUG: SearchController.filter:   
[2019-09-06 11:47:40] production.ERROR: It is unsafe to run Dusk in production. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): It is unsafe to run Dusk in production. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\dusk\\src\\DuskServiceProvider.php:43)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(607): Laravel\\Dusk\\DuskServiceProvider->register()
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\ProviderRepository.php(75): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->register(Object(Laravel\\Dusk\\DuskServiceProvider))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(584): Illuminate\\Foundation\\ProviderRepository->load(Array)
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->registerConfiguredProviders()
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(210): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(162): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(146): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 {main}
"} 
[2019-09-06 11:47:40] testing.DEBUG: SearchController.filter:   
[2019-09-06 11:47:40] testing.DEBUG: SearchController.getAlert:
```

I can't understand why dusk considers that i am running in a production environment. I am running in local normally and testing during the dusk tests.

Comment: PS. Forgot to say: thanks for any comments/pointers, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do the same tests fail each time?

Comment: No, sometimes a test can run fine, and then i repeat it a minute later and the self same test will fail. I write this having just witnessed this exact scenario on my second dev box. Its as if there is a seperate dusk task in the background that is kicked off when dusk runs and decides env is at production. It doesn't seem to be directly coupled to the types of tests i am performing. The only thing that does seem coincidental is it happens around 8-12 seconds after a test starts.

Comment: [2019-09-06 16:17:21] testing.DEBUG: >test1Search: start  
[2019-09-06 16:17:29] testing.DEBUG: SearchController.filter:   
[2019-09-06 16:17:29] production.ERROR: It is unsafe to run Dusk in production. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): It is unsafe to run Dusk in production. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\assetH\\vendor\\laravel\\dusk\\src\\DuskServiceProvider.php:43)
[stacktrace]

Comment: Very odd, not sure how to debug this. Can you remove all Dusk test classes and restore them one by one?

Comment: Jonas: just to confirm, i ran the same test three times. Two times the production.ERROR message came up, the third time it didn't. So the error is not even consistent on tests. This is why i think it is some background polling issue.

Comment: I am getting the same issues. If I keep running the tests (usually three times) the test passes. First failure gives me the 'unsafe to run Dusk in production' error, second failure is because dusk tells me it cannot find a selector, and then the test usually passes on the next attempt.